# How to analyze memory performance per data structure in C?

Tags: c, memory, profiling, read-write, memory-profiling

I want to make an analytical profiling in an application, in order to have an overall knowledge of how it behaves in terms of memory accesses. More specifically, I need to see analytically the number of reads and writes per data structure. For instance, if I have a single linked list in my app, I want to know that for a specific input the program does x reads and y writes for this specific list. Is there any tool doing such analysis?

Comment: I doubt it. You'll probably have to do it manually.

Comment: It's hardly possible in C. You can use data breakpoints in many debuggers, but this would require your linked list to be at a specific place (or all its items, depending on what you want to detect). It would be far easier to just add instrumentation to the functions which operate on the list.

Comment: You could start by profiling the code.